# Appropriate way of asking the user for feet and inches on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, units-of-measurement

I'm implementing a form where the user is asked for a measurement. Depending on the locale, the user will be entering either meters or feet/inches.

Naively, my current implementation asks for a decimal point to be used with only feet. e.g., 2.5 feet would equal 2′ 6″ which is fairly misleading from my understanding. I'm not in a [country that hasn't adopted to the metric system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrication#Overview), so it wasn't obvious to me at the time.

There's a few possibilities and problems I see:

- Show two `EditText` fields, one for feet one for inches. This makes layout design difficult since I'm also allowing the user to enter meters, which will only need one `EditText`. A possibility is to make one hidden at run time.
- Using one `EditText`, I can't seem to find an `android:inputType` that allows for number input plus double primes and primes, or double quotes and apostrophes. e.g. 3′ 5″ or 3' 5". It means the `EditText` would have to use the standard alphabet keyboard which makes it slightly hindering to the user.
- Also, with one `EditText`, I am happy to (and already doing so for just a single entry with meters and feet without inches), to suffix the `EditText` after the user loses focus, and remove the suffix when being focused again. This does make the code more complex for a simple input field.

Are there any other options for this?

Comment: As a user I would think anything but two EditText's clearly labeled `feet` and `inches` would be confusing. To put both into a single edit text it's not clear how you could describe the input format short of having a separate 'readme' page. Plus I've got a feeling that a significant number of people probably would probably mix up the single/double quotes on feet/inches (i.e. 3" 6').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realised soon after posting:

Why not create a [`NumberPicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) popup or `Spinner` when the user focuses on the `EditText`. This would only show up for imperial measurements.

Comment: In truth this is probably the best solution.  Clunky but best.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking off the top of my head you can use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) to check for when the user types a space.  When that occurs, suffix in the `'` at the end and let the user type the inches.

Or, always append the suffix to the end and push it down beyond the cursor every time the user types.  When the user presses space then jump the cursor over and put `"` beyond it.

It may or may not be messy from a user flow perspective (I haven't tried or seen it), but it could solve some problems.  You can continue to force the user to type only numerical values which keeps the number keyboard up instead of letters.  They don't have to swap keyboards or do long-key presses to type a single character. It also shows the intentions to the user as he/she types.

Comment: So what kind of inputType would be used? If it's set to numeric, I don't think spaces are allowed.

Comment: Oh I see. Hmm... You're right. TextWatcher may or may not catch that.  If it can, then you probably can programmatically force a space.  If not then it may have to be something you enforce yourself.  Americans.  When we we learn and adapt to better ways?

Answer (score 0):

```
 edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                String input = edittext.getText().toString();
                if (input.length() == 1) {
                    input = input + "'";
                    edittext.setText(input);
                    int pos = edittext.getText().length();
                    edittext.setSelection(pos);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```